# iPhone - Which direction is positive theta?

Tags: ios, iphone, angle

I wanted to use the iPhone's rotation system to be able to have an object follow below a line the user rotates. To do this, I need the angle at which the line is being measured as. When I set the rotation equal to `M_PI_2`, the object rotates 90 degrees counterclockwise. Which begs the question: Is the iPhone's angle-measurement system backwards? In other words, in portrait orientation, screen facing you, is positive theta clockwise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after doing some researching.
Since the iPhone's +x axis is to the right (same orientation as question) and the +y axis is down, it should make sense that the +theta direction is clockwise.

**The normal axes**

[image: Normal Cartesian Axes]

**The iPhone's Axes**
[image: iPhone Cartesian Axes]